# Getting web fonts to work with phonegap and android - how?

Tags: android, css, cordova, webfonts

Does PhoneGap support web fonts, and if so how do you use them. I've currently got this code in my page, but it doesn't work when loaded into the emulator (inside an android app, I've not tried loading the page through the browser)...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticrapRegular';
    src: url('fonts/helveticrap-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/helveticrap-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/helveticrap-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/helveticrap-webfont.svg#webfontHlJ0Jib3') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: "HelveticrapRegular", "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans serif";
}
```

When I load my page up in firefox, it does work, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

It may help to say that the font CSS was generated by fontsquirrel

Thanks :) Joel

Answer (score 8):

I had a problem with using a custom font in the Woff format. Then I converted it from Woff to Ttf and it worked on my Android device. So there might be a problem with using Woff format.

**So, conversion from .woff to .ttf might solve the problem.**

Comment: This approach worked for me. I used this tool to convert: http://orionevent.comxa.com/

Answer (score 5):

I've had no problem getting PhoneGap to recognize web fonts.  If WebKit will do it then Android and iOS will do it.
In a project I'm working on now, currently only tested on Android:

```
@font-face{
 font-family: MyFont; 
 src: url('../fonts/my_font.ttf') format('truetype');
 src: url('../fonts/my_font.otf') format('opentype');
```

then on a style as

```
font-family:MyFont, arial, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Webfonts are broken in android 2.1, it's a known bug, unfortunately.

Comment: @AdonisK. Web fonts work fine on Android 4.1. I own a 4.1 device (Galaxy Note 2) and use it regularly for development, in which I use webfonts on a regular basis.

Comment: It was a remote url issue